# XP Virtual Mode in Windows 7, network access for installed apps?

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, microsoft-access, windows

I have the joy of having to manage a Microsoft Access form that was designed in Access 2003. The MDB is converted to an MDE for security reasons. However, I'm running Windows 7 with Office 2007 (including Access 2007). Access 2007 doesn't allow you to convert an MDB to MDE that is compatible with Access 2003.  Wow, that was a mouthful...

So, to rectify the situation and to keep from having to use a slooooow laptop here, I've just setup XP Virtual Mode in my Windows 7 install. Access 2003 is installed into it and works great... there's just one problem. The Access 2003 install cannot make use of the User DSN's my Win7 install has, and because the XP mode VM uses a generic local user, it cannot access my SQL databases from within the VM.

Any thoughts on how I can get around this? Should I add the XP vm to our company's domain and treat it like any other computer? I'm assuming I'll have to change the networking so that it's got access (doesn't appear to have any now).

I don't need a full walkthrough, but would love some tips/suggestions. At the end of the day, I need my Access 2003 instance to be able to access network resources, preferably using my AD login info (passthru), but I can create a static DB account if needed.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're stuck adding the VM to the domain and using a real login. Virtualized machines, even the "XP Mode" one can be thought of as independent of the host OS (including all it's DSN configurations and Authentication).

Comment: Thanks Chris - that's not a real big deal if I have to go that route, I can work with it. I'll give that a shot when I get into the office tomorrow.